# is it possible to show widget only for a certain android version?

Tags: android, android-widget, apk, android-version

is it possible to show widget in "Add to home screen > Widgets" Dialog only for a certain android version without uploading two APKs and assigning to proper SDK version numbers?

Comment: it would be interesting, not only dependent on version but more things.

Comment: of course it would :) i just wrote android version because i am having problems with 2.1 because of the API restrictions.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I have a way to do it without any code e.g.:

In your res\values dir create a bools.xml file:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <bool name="honeycombOrAbove">false</bool>
</resources>`

Create a values-v11 dir (for honeycomb or above values), copy the file to it and set the value to true.

Then in the manifest for the widget receiver use: android:enabled="@bool/honeycombOrAbove". I also used it in the configuration activity for the widget.

This means the widget is disabled at install time.

Comment: Brilliant solution since it works when the application is installed and this is more of a provisioning issue.  Thanks for this - you saved me a bunch of hunting for a solution this morning.

Comment: Perfect solution. This really should have been the accepted answer!

Comment: Very clever solution ! Definitely the best answer !

Answer (score 9):

You can do it with the componentEnableSetting.
Just disable the widget you don't want to have listed.
The change will get active after phone-restart.

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
String str1 = "org.classname.to.widget.provider";
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(context, str1);
PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();

int versioncode = Integer.valueOf(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK);    

//enable widget
packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, 1, 1);

//disable widget
packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, 2, 1);
```

Comment: Yep this solution works although i had to change it a little bit since this code looks for version number of the app and not the SDK. Thanks a lot!

Comment: what did you change? i can edit and then you can approve the answer as the solution for your problem

Comment: just this line "int versioncode =  Integer.valueOf(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK);" and added if conditions for 2.1 to disable and 2.2 or above to enable

Comment: Approved. What i like about this answer is that you can use it to disable widget for almost every possible situation. Thanks

Comment: You should use `int VERSION.SDK_INT` instead of the deprecated and parsing requiring `String VERSION.SDK`.