# How to support resizable widgets?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-manifest, android-appwidget

My app supports this API range

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
```

It also has a single basic app widget that could be resizable but since the older APIs do not support android:resizeMode the manifest lists this widget in few predefined sizes.

What is the best strategy for supporting both old and new phones?  For example, having old phones seeing a few predefined widget sizes and having new phones seeing a single resizable widget.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, one solution I found is to have two sets of widgets, one for old phones and one for new phones. Define two boolean resources, one that will be true for old phones and one that will be true new phones and use them to enable/disable the widgets in the manifest

[is it possible to show widget only for a certain android version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7064035/is-it-possible-to-show-widget-only-for-a-certain-android-version)