# ICS home screen widget shows up in Pre-ics device

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-2.3-gingerbread

How would I prevent my ICS only widget showing up on older phones while still keeping my app backwards compatible. Currently my task manager runs on froyo and beyond but I have an ICS and up widget that I only want to show to compatible users.

Comment: If you mean home screen widget please see the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7064035/is-it-possible-to-show-widget-only-for-a-certain-android-version/7262498#7262498

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way currently on Android to do this. Just make two builds.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a check on the device to see what version it is, using something such as

```
Build.VERSION.RELEASE
```

to query which android version it is. Once determined you could make the widget only available to that version level or higher.

Comment: How would you make it available/not available??

Comment: Assuming it is set in a view of some sort (I've never dealt with widgets) you can change the setVisibility() option: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility(int)

Comment: Assuming you can set it to INVISIBLE (which I doubt), this will not remove it from the device's widgets list.