# Adding support for Fragments in API 10

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-compatibility

I've been building an app that untill recently had `minSdkVersion="14"`, but i want to change that and add compatability for api 10. The first problem i had was with styles but i sort-off fixed it by using `Theme.AppCompat`. Now i have problems in my code, the first one is that i'm using a lot of fragments.

The first fragments that appear in my app are:

```
FirstRunNotice firstRunNotice = new FirstRunNotice();
firstRunNotice.show(getFragmentManager(), "WhatDoesThisStringEvenDo?");
//.show method gives an error
```

This is just an inner class within my activity that extends `DialogFragment`. How do i make this work on API 10? If i change it to `android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment` it seems to take the errors away (using Android Studio) but it's weird because if i use it on one inner class (i have the DialogFragments) it takes the error away on both. Why is that?

Also, if i were to change all `Fragment` extended classes to `android.support.v4.app.Fragment, .DialogFragment, .ListFragment`... What would that do in case i run my app on a higher API, let's say 19? Would the app use the compatability library or would it know to use the class from that API? And is there a difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since now you want to support Gingerbread and lower, you *have* to use the `android.support.v4.app.*` Fragment classes for your app to compile and run. 
The call to `getFragmentManager()` should also be replaced with `getSupportFragmentManager()`

It is also important to note that calling `getSupportFragmentManager()` is only part of [`FragmentActivity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html) and [`ActionBarActivity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html) (the latter is an extention of the former. It is a part of Google's ActionBarCompat library).

This is because since the support Fragments are an addition to the Android system, there needs to be a way to implement them without relying too much on the Android internals (since Gingerbread and lower have no notion of a `Fragment`).

> but it's weird because if i use it on one inner class (i have the
>   DialogFragments) it takes the error away on both. Why is that?

It's likely you are encountering multiple Android Lint errors

> What would that do in case i run my app on a higher API

Nothing, the support library works with new API versions as well. Of course, if you had previous code that *required* API 11+, then you need to figure out a way to backport that as well.

> Would the app use the compatability library or would it know to use
>   the class from that API?

The support `Fragment` [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html) says:

> When running on Android 3.0 or above, this implementation is still
>   used; it does not try to switch to the framework's implementation.

Support Fragments will always be used. Usually, this isn't an issue.

Comment: Thanks for the explenation! The only thing i cant get to work is `getFragmentManager()`, if i just change it to `getSupportFragmentManager()` the method doesnt resolve...

Comment: @Squeazer Are you now extending `FragmentActivity` or `ActionBarActivity`? I assumed so because you are using `Theme.AppCompat`.

Comment: The first activity extends `Activity`. It's basically a splash screen for the application that loads some xml files from the web. The `gerFragmentManager()` is called from `onCreate()` and from an inner `AsyncTask` class.

Comment: You do need to extend one of the classes I mentioned for `getSupportFragmentManager()` to resolve (I edited the answer to include this info)

Comment: This worked perfectly thanks! Just one more theng, if you could point me in the right direction... I also have a widget with a list, it uses `RemoteViewsService`, `RemoteViewsFactory` etc.... It's API 11+, how can i add compatability for that? The widget is nothing fancy, just a list with some items in it.

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot. You could use LinearLayout to sort of simulate a list (no scrolling either on API 10 and lower, so that's another restriction).

Comment: Oh that's too bad. Is there a way to disable the widget in lower APIs? So it wouldnt show up in the widget list?

Comment: Nevermind, found the answer here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7064035/is-it-possible-to-show-widget-only-for-a-certain-android-version)
Thanks for the help!